# Почему не работает overflow-x: auto на iPhone в модальном окне?

Tags: css, reactjs, iphone

Есть сайт на React. Открывается модальное окно. В нем есть 2 списка карточек с горизонтальным скроллом. И он работает и на десктопе и на Android, но ни в какую не хочет работать на iPhone. Хотя эти же карточки отлично работают вне модального окна.
На родителе карточек стоит "overflow-x: auto;". Пробовал добавлять - "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"  - безрезультатно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На данный момент нашел костыльное решение через js - https://codepen.io/thenutz/pen/VwYeYEE. Только вместо mouse эвентов -  использовать, естественно, touch (e.pageX => e.touches[0].pageX )

Answer (score 0):

Я решал проблему таким образом

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` на родителе.

Если не получится со значением `overflow-x: auto;`, то попробуй сделать его `overflow-x: scroll;`.

```
.parent {
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Нет, увы, не работает, и это тоже пробовал, добавлю в вопрос.